# Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->getUncaughtExceptionPreHandler()Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler; (light greylist, reflection)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I use kotlin Coroutines & retrofit in my project. Sometimes my app crashes with this error

```
Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->getUncaughtExceptionPreHandler()Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler; (light greylist, reflection)
```

I couldn't understand what is happening.

My ViewModel :

```
 private val parentJob = SupervisorJob()

    private val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Default


    private val scope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)

    private val repository: RegisterRepository = RegisterRepository(service)


   scope.launch {
            val registerResult = repository.postRegister(registerBody)

            if (registerResult != null) {
                authToken = "${registerResult[0].token_type}  ${registerResult[0].access_token}"
                SharedPref.write(AUTH_TOKEN, "$authToken")
            }

            registerResponse.postValue(registerResult)
        }
```

The Repository Class

```
suspend fun postRegister(registerBody: RegisterBody): MutableList<RegisterResponse>? {

        val response = safeApiCall(
            call = { api.register(registerBody).await() },
            errorMessage = "Error posting register data"
        )


        return response!!.data!!.toMutableList()

    }
```

Comment: Look at this [issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/822). It has been already fixed, so probably it'll be enough to increase coroutines lib version.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: On what android version do you receive this exception?

Comment: my device android version is 9

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Anybody has any clue?